# Refreshing page shows file not found error

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I am using **apache** server for an **angularJS** web-app. Its purely based on AngularJS/HTML5 and has no server side programming like php or others.

When I say `localhost` on my browser (Chrome 49+), it takes me to `http://localhost/Login/Index` as per the routes defined. But when I refresh the page, browser says `The requested URL /Login/Index was not found on this server.`

I went through some posts on *stackoverflow* and tried this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried removing few lines and it shows me some error while refreshing the page. So this means that .htaccess file is being applied. So I suppose the problem must be with the `RewriteRule`. What should I write in the `RewriteRule`? Any other quick/better way to solve this problem?